# How to rotate a 2D object by 90 degrees in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I need to rotate 2D `GameObject` by 90 degrees by z axis. So I already tried `transform.RotateAround` but still rotates in a complete circle:

```
transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, new Vector3 (0, 0, -90),
        50f * Time.deltaTime)
```

I need to stop it by 90. How can I do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDwsX.png)

Comment: `transform.Rotate(0f,0f,90f);`? What code did you use when you used `transform.RotateAround`? Please share your research.

Comment: @Ruzihm it rotates by the center of ```GameObject```, I need to roate by point as in picture

Comment: @Ruzihm ```transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, new Vector3 (0, 0, -90), 50f * Time.deltaTime)``` I used this. But its rotate all circle

Comment: If it's a simple rotation that does not exceed +/- 360 degrees just set the `transform.rotation` property. Otherwise look into the `Quaternion` class; it has several methods to handle rotations. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

Comment: Regarding rotating from a fixed point rather than the centre: One simple option to consider is simply to put the visible object you want to rotate inside a parent GameObject centred at the desired pivot point (i.e. in the position of a “hinge”), and then rotate that parent GameObject. In specific cases (e.g. a door) it could even make sense to make that parent object a _visible_ hinge.

Comment: If the 2D object is a sprite, you could also consider changing the pivot point of the sprite in Unity's Sprite Editor if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) that rotates based on `deltaTime` and keeps track of how far it has rotated, stopping once it hits `90`. Use `Mathf.Min` to be sure not to rotate past 90.

```
private isRotating = false;

// speed & amount must be positive, change axis to control direction
IEnumerator DoRotation(float speed, float amount, Vector3 axis)
{
    isRotating = true;
    float rot = 0f;
    while (rot < amount)
    {
        yield return null;
        float delta = Mathf.Min(speed * Time.deltaTime, amount - rot);
        transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, axis, delta);
        rot += delta;
    }
    isRotating = false;
}
```

Then when you want to start rotating, start the coroutine if it isnt already rotating:

```
if (!isRotating)
{
    StartCoroutine(DoRotation(50f, 90f, Vector3.back));
}
```

---

It's slightly better form to save the Coroutine itself instead of using a flag. This lets you do stuff like stop the rotation at any point.

```
private Coroutine rotatingCoro;

// speed & amount must be positive, change axis to control direction
IEnumerator DoRotation(float speed, float amount, Vector3 axis)
{
    float rot = 0f;
    while (rot < amount)
    {
        yield return null;
        float delta = Mathf.Min(speed * Time.deltaTime, amount - rot);
        transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, axis, delta);
        rot += delta;
    }

    rotatingCoro = null;
}

// ...

if (rotatingCoro != null)
{
    rotatingCoro = StartCoroutine(DoRotation(50f, 90f, Vector3.back));
}

// ...

// call to stop rotating immediately
void StopRotating()
{
    if (rotatingCoro != null) 
    {
        StopCoroutine(rotatingCoro);
        rotatingCoro = null;
    }
}
```